# Cannot render component after signin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

I've a react-native app build with expo, the signin page works fine, however, when user attemp to signin and the app change the screen to the maintabbar, the app thors these errors:

1 - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

2 - Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `circle` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

3 - Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `path` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

4 - Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `polyline` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

this is the signin page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Image, ActivityIndicator, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useUserAuth } from '../../../hooks/useUserAuth';

import { ISession } from './SigIn.types';

import {
  Container,
  InputArea,
  CustomButton,
  CustomButtonText,
  SignMessageButton,
  SignMessageButtonText,
  SignMessageButtonTextBold,
  InputSecondArea,
  styles,
} from './SigIn.styled';

export const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const { singIn } = useUserAuth();

  const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
  const email = watch('email', '');
  const password = watch('password', '');

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleMessageButtonClick = () => {
    navigation.reset({
      routes: [{ name: 'SignUp' }],
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (data: ISession) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const sessionSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string().required(),
        password: Yup.string().required(),
      });

      await sessionSchema.validate(data);

      const session: ISession = {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
      };

      const response = await singIn(session);

      if (response !== 201) throw response;

      navigation.reset({
        routes: [{ name: 'MainTabBar' }],
      });
    } catch (errStatus) {
      switch (errStatus) {
        case 400:
          alert('Dados Incorretos');
          break;
        case 401:
          alert('Nao autenticado');
          break;
        case 500:
          alert('Erro no servidor');
          break;
      }
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    register('email');
    register('password');
  }, [register]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Image
        style={styles.imagestyle}
        source={require('../../../../assets/icons/logo.svg')}
      />

      <InputArea>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Email ou usuario'
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(t) => setValue('email', t)}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder='Senha'
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(t) => setValue('password', t)}
          secureTextEntry={true}
        />

        <CustomButton onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          {loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator color='white' />
          ) : (
            <CustomButtonText>Entrar</CustomButtonText>
          )}
        </CustomButton>
      </InputArea>

      <InputSecondArea>
        <SignMessageButton onPress={handleMessageButtonClick}>
          <SignMessageButtonText>
            {' '}
            Ainda não é cadastrado?
          </SignMessageButtonText>
          <SignMessageButtonTextBold>CADASTRAR</SignMessageButtonTextBold>
        </SignMessageButton>
      </InputSecondArea>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

and this is the MainTabBar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { CustomTabBar } from '../../components/CustomTabBar/CustomTabBar';
import { Home } from '../../screens/Home/Home';
import { SearchAnimal } from '../../screens/Animal/SearchAnimal/SearchAnimal';
import { Dashboard } from '../../screens/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import { Config } from '../../screens/Config/Config';

const TabBar = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const MainTabBar: React.FC = () => (
  <TabBar.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
    <TabBar.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
    <TabBar.Screen name='Search' component={SearchAnimal} />
    <TabBar.Screen name='List' component={Dashboard} />
    <TabBar.Screen name='Config' component={Config} />
  </TabBar.Navigator>
);
```

Comment: did u install react-native-svg?  Don't remember you can use .svg in Image component like that.

Comment: and your useEffect with register() doesn't make sense. you should probably try [] instead of [register] so u only register it once.

Comment: the register is from the [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for react-native.

Comment: Not sure about the last three errors (I believe they are coming from the component you are navigationg to), but the first error appears because you are doing a `setLoading` after your navigation.

Comment: I checked the documentation and there isn't a need for the useEffect. What happens is when you change page (component unmount) it throws memory leak error.

Comment: did you see the get stared video from the link I gave? where dd you see that there's no need for useEffect?